# SSRS 2008 query returns different results in SSRS than directly in Management Studio

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hoping someone can help here.  I have an order print report in SSRS 2008 that is returning the correct results when I run it directly in a query in Mgmt Studio but the same query in SSRS is not.  I've simplified the query I'm using to just a few tables to make it simpler here. This is just a text query in my SSRS dataset:

```
select   o.order_num,  ol.prod_num,  ol.prod_desc1 as com1, ol.prod_desc2 as com2
from [order] o
left outer join order_line ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num
where o.order_num = '09182272' and **(ol.prod_desc1 NOT LIKE '*%' and ol.prod_num <> 'C')**
UNION ALL
select    o.order_num,  ol.prod_num, ol.prod_desc1 as com1, ol.prod_desc2 as com2
from [order_history] o
left outer join order_history_line ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num
where o.order_num = '09182272' and (ol.prod_desc1 NOT LIKE '*%' and ol.prod_num <> 'C')
```

I don't want to see any order_line (order detail lines) where the desc starts with "*" or the prod_num = "C".  When I run it in Mgmt Studio, I don't get those lines -- but when I run it in SSRS, they ARE returned.  The only difference with the 2 queries is that in SSRS the o.order_num is a paramater and here I have it hard coded.  Any ideas?  thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out -- I had to clear the cache.  Found this very helpful!

Comment: cool. It would be awesome if you actually posted what you did to "clear the cache" incase someone else has the same issue. And then dont forget to accept your answer as soon as SO allows you to. Its basically the checkmark next to your answer under the up/down vote buttons.